# grep - exit with 1 - if match

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I have a bash function like so:

```
run_mongo(){
  mongo foo bar baz 2>&1  # send stderr to stdout
}
```

unfortunately this mongo command doesn't exit with 1 if there is error, so I have to match on stdout/stderr

is there some way to exit with code > 0 with grep if there is a first match? something like this:

```
run_mongo | grep -e "if stdout/stderr matches this we exit with 1"
```

I assume the way to do this would be like so:

```
run_mongo | grep -e "if stdout/stderr matches" | killer
```

where killer is a program that dies as soon as it gets its first bit of stdin.

Comment: If the mongo command exits successfully when there was an error, and there is no option to make it do otherwise, **this is a bug.** *Please* report it.  That's not even a difficult bug to fix, and then developers won't have to hack around it like you're doing.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you can do it with `grep -vz` which tells `grep` to find lines that don't match the pattern you give it (`-v`) and to read the entire input at once (`z`), so that one match means the whole thing fails:

```
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | grep -zqv foo && echo no || echo yes
yes
$ printf 'foo\nbar\n' | grep -zq foo && echo no || echo yes
no
```

So, in your case, something like:

```
run_mongo(){
  mongo foo bar baz 2>&1 | grep -vzq "whatever means failure" 
}

if run_mongo; then
 echo "Worked!"
else
  echo "Failed!"
fi
```

---

If you want to avoid reading the whole output, just use another tool. Perl, for example:

```
mongo foo bar baz 2>&1 | perl -ne 'exit 1 if /whatever means failure/'
```

Comment: the only question in my mind - does the pipe clean itself up consistently if the last command dies first? or if any of the non-first commands die first? I would guess no...

Comment: @AlexanderMills that's not relevant to the question you're asking, since you said the process fails without actually returning, but no it doesn't. If that's the behavior you want and assuming your default shell is bash, then you need `set -o pipefail` (see [Get exit status of process that's piped to another](//unix.stackexchange.com/a/73180)).

Comment: so using `set -o pipefail` means the line that sets the pipe will exit with the exit status of the last command?

Comment: @AlexanderMills see `help set`: "pipefail     the return value of a pipeline is the status of the last command *to exit with a non-zero status*, or zero if no command exited with a non-zero status"

Comment: I don't see why you need the `-z` option if you want to exit ASAP. Are you just making sure that `mongo` is allowed to finish?

Comment: No, @Kusalananda. That was the best I could come up with. How else would we do this?  The `-z` essentially makes the whole thing act as a single line, so even one match is enough to exit with a non-0 status when running with `-v`. So this would ensure that no matches anywhere in the file exits with 0 and any match anywhere exits with 1. Am I missing something obvious again?

Comment: @terdon You probably don't miss anything. It's just me that can't wrap my head around it properly.

Comment: @Kusalananda compare `seq 10 | grep -vq 5; echo $?` to `seq 10 | grep -zvq 5; echo $?`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I went for `! seq 10 | grep -q 5; echo $?` in my answer.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to terminate as quickly as possible:

```bash
run_mongo () {
    ! mongo foo bar baz 2>&1 | grep -q 'bad-pattern'
}
```

This would run `mongo` and terminate the function as soon as possible if the pattern `bad-pattern` is found in the output. When the pattern is matched, `grep` exits immediately, and `mongo` receives a PIPE signal as soon as it tries to write to the dead pipe.

Due to the `!`, the exit status of the pipeline will be inverted, i.e. it will be zero if the pattern wasn't found or non-zero if it was found.

If you need to let `mongo` finish writing its output:

```bash
run_mongo () {
    ! mongo foo bar baz 2>&1 | grep 'bad-pattern' > /dev/null
}
```

This is the same as the first piece of code in this answer, but `grep` now consumes all output from `mongo`.

Comment: what is the ! for?

Comment: @AlexanderMills It inverts the exit status of the subsequent command or pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

@terdon's solution looks good, since I am a Node.js fanboy, I just wrote a program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

process.stdin.resume().once('data', function () {
   process.exit(1);
});
```

then in my bash script have:

```
run_mongo(){
  mongo foo bar baz 2>&1
}

exit_if_match(){
    grep "$1" | "./node_modules/.bin/imminent_suicide"
}

run_mongo "foo" "bar" | exit_if_match "errmsg"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'if stdout/stderr matches this' |
    awk '$0 ~ "if stdout/stderr matches this" { exit 1; }' ; echo $?
```